# pdftools in R performing differently across machines

Tags: r, ubuntu, pdf

I'm noticing an issue where the pdftools package in R seems to be performing differently when run locally on my Windows 7 machine versus when I run it on a shared Ubuntu server via ssh.

My code:

```
download.file("http://www.nber.org/lbid/docs/LinkCO95Guide.pdf",
          "1995codebook.pdf", 
          mode = "wb", 
          method = "libcurl")
codebook <- pdf_text("1995codebook.pdf")
```

On my local windows 7 machine, the object *codebook* shows up as "Large character (258 elements, 710.2 Kb)", whereas on the Ubuntu server it shows up as "Large character (258 elements, 701.9 Kb)".

As you might imagine, this is causing problems for me downstream where code that works on my local machine is not producing the same results on the Ubuntu server. Looking at the text contained in *codebook* the first difference I notice right away is that where the version produced on Windows has "\r\n" the version produced on Ubuntu only has "\n" instead (I rely on "\r\n" downstream).

Why would that character series be different? Might it have something to do with encoding? Any help appreciated on what's causing this and how I can get the same results on both machines.

One last thing to mention: I had to install the poppler library to my home directory on the Ubuntu server (don't have sudo access) in order to get pdftools to install:

```
apt-get source poppler
cd poppler-0.24.5
./configure --prefix=$HOME/myapps
make
make install
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/myapps/lib/pkgconfig
```

After having done so, install.packages("pdftools") seems to run correctly. And pdftools loads without issue. So if it's a bad install I'm not sure what has gone wrong.

Comment: any discrepancy can be b/c of the poppler library in use or encoding issues. what did you do. what is the doc. where is the reproducible code you were instructed to provide when you submitted a q?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The doc is in the R code above. That's all the code needed for reproduction in R other than install.packages("pdftools") and library(pdftools). The code I used to get the poppler library was:
apt-get source poppler;
cd poppler-0.24.5;
./configure --prefix=$HOME/myapps;
make;
make install;
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH = $HOME/myapps/lib/pkgconfig;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- Windows has different line endings, this is [extensively documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). This alone accounts for the size difference
- Even after the download, you can convert between both conventions. One tool to do so is `dos2unix` which you can get via `apt-get install dos2unix`
- You are making your life too complicated by building poppler. As the [`configure` script for pdftools says](https://github.com/ropensci/pdftools/blob/master/configure#L9), just install the library via `apt-get install libpoppler-cpp-dev`

However: most sane programs, and R included, treat `\r\n` and `n` identically so your imported data should be the same.  If yours does not,
use `dos2unix` or equivalent tools to convert as needed.  In the longer run you want your code to not care.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I ran that line from the configure script I got "permission denied" from the server (don't have root or sudo access). The imported text in R is different (windows gave "\r\n" while ubuntu gives "\n") but that would be explained by the wiki article. I was using the line endings to process/split the text, so I just adapted my code to the difference.

Comment: You need `sudo apt-get install libpoppler-cpp-dev`